# Can't pass [[Float]] array into Objective-C++

Tags: c++, arrays, swift, pointers

I am processing sound inside my app. The DSP algorithm is written in `C++`. I need to pass data into `C++` and then pass the result into audio subsystem in `Swift`.

To pass data into `C++` I've written an `Objective-C++` class:

```
#define BufferSize 10240

@interface EffectsWrapper : NSObject
-   (void) processBuffer: (float * _Nonnull *_Nonnull) dataIn ofSize: (int) dataSize intoOutputBuffer: (float * _Nonnull *_Nonnull) dataOut;
@end

@implementation EffectsWrapper
-   (void) processBuffer: (float * _Nonnull *_Nonnull) dataIn ofSize: (int) dataSize intoOutputBuffer: (float * _Nonnull *_Nonnull) dataOut
{
    for(int channel = 0; channel < 2; channel ++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i ++)
        {
            float data =  dataIn[channel][i];
            dataOut[channel][i] = data;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

As you can see, right now it just copies the input into the output.

The invocation of the method is done inside `MTAudioProcessingTapProcessCallback` closure, which is described as a property of `MyClass`. `EffectsWrapper` is also a property of this class.

To "process" data, firstly, I create input and output arrays like so:

```
var dataIn: [[Float]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: framesCount), count: 2)
var dataOut: [[Float]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: framesCount), count: 2)
```

Secondly, I fill in the input array with data. And then I invoke `EffectsWrapper.process` method like so:

```
let dataInPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: [UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataIn[0]), UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataIn[1])])
let dataOutPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: [UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataOut[0]), UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataOut[1])])
myClass.effectsWrapper.processBuffer(dataInPtr, ofSize: Int32(framesCount), intoOutputBuffer: dataOutPtr)
```

The problem is that data inside `EffectsWrapper` is complete garbage. Sometimes it even throws me an allocation error. And I do not get why the pointers I create are pointing onto some random places in memory rather than the elements of arrays I need them to point to.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that code like

```
let dataInPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: [UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataIn[0]), UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: dataIn[1])])
```

uses **implicit bridging** to create `UnsafePointer`s from arrays.  Those pointers are (indirectly) saved for later use, which is undefined behavior. See `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafepointer and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer.  As stated there,

> The pointer created through implicit bridging of an instance or of an
>   array’s elements is only valid during the execution of the called
>   function. Escaping the pointer to use after the execution of the
>   function is undefined behavior. In particular, do not use implicit
>   bridging when calling an `UnsafePointer` initializer.

Before trying to solve this problem in a way that works, one should explore the possibility of writing a wrapper in such a way that an input or output buffer passed between Swift and the wrapper is a region in memory where all channel data is stored contiguously.  Then the buffers won't need to be treated as arrays of pointers, and passing arrays of, say, floats between Objective-C(++) and Swift is easier.

Comment: I've decided to use 1D arrays and pass pointers to those using `&` operator. `C++` stuff treat audio channels as separate arrays anyway. Works like a charm.